# iOS open iBook file in App Bundle

Tags: ios

I have a iBook file (say SampleiBook.iba) within the app bundle (not in documents directory).
Now i just want to open SampleiBook from within app. I tried this,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleiBook" ofType:@".iba"];
NSString *stringURL = [@"ibooks://" stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

the iBook application gets opened, showing only the files within the iBook application.  But i want the one in app bundle to be opened.

Please guide me in achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to load the .iba (iBooks Author Book) file from your app. This not going to work because .iba is the file that contains your source for the .ibooks file type that I think you really want to load.

I am writing in swift these days. Here is a swift example I just ran. Assumes that the unbutton is wired from a nib or storyboard

```
    @IBOutlet weak var iBooksBtn:     UIButton! 
    @IBAction func iBooksBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let ibookPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Cupertino",
                                                               ofType: "ibooks")!
        let url       = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ibookPath)
        let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:url!)
        interactionController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(CGRectZero,   
                inView:self.iBooksBtn, animated:false)
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Copied the code above - and pasted in my project to test. Only changed the name of the file, and the type (to "Test" and type: "pdf") It runs fine - no error or crashes. But nothing shows up on the screen??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to open the iBook in iBooks.

You can easily create an instance for the iBook in mian bundle:

```
NSURL *iBookResourceURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SampleiBook" withExtension:@"iba"];
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
        [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: iBookResourceURL];
```

Comment: I tried this, but app crashes at this line,     UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:iBookResourceURL];

Comment: What does the debug output say!

Comment: In device log it says that app crashes at this line

Comment: - (IBAction)didClickMe:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSURL *iBookResourceURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SampleiBook" withExtension:@"iba"];
    
    self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:iBookResourceURL];
}

Comment: iBookCollections               0x00064b4e -[ViewController didClickMe:] (ViewController.m:35)

Comment: this is what i get in device log's crash report

Comment: That is not enough to go on, add `All exceptions` breakpoint in the breakpoint pane. And try and get a more explanative error message

Comment: Sorry that still is not telling anything, except the line on which is crashed. We need to error message, console output (fully not just the line) and the condition that was raised.

Comment: <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'

Comment: So the `iBookResourceURL` is nil because it can not find the `SampleiBook` in the main bundle.

Comment: I added the file in Bundle. It exists

Comment: This is basic debugging. Check that the file exists in the bundle, check the name and check if the method returns an URL. I can not help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It says invalid file scheme. Same code works for pdf file but not for iBook. Not sure whether SampleiBook.iba is a file or an application that is opened by iBook. Will look into it. Thanks